# D3.js background gitter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i wasnt quite sure what to call this question but so far i have been unable to find what im looking for.

First an image:

[image]

This is taken from `chart.js`

Right now im trying to create my own costum chart but i want it to feel abit like `chart.js` so  here is my chart created with `D3`:
[image]

Now on the image from Chart.js you can see the background has some sort of indexing. I was wondering how is that possible with `D3`?

Comment: you need to look for [Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) and [Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152) not `stacked bar chart`

Comment: @ozil im not quite sure i know what you mean?

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to create a chart in `d3.js` just like figure?

Comment: So you want a [chart with a grid](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/11110940)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Exactly.

Comment: All you have to do for that is adjust the tick sizes. See the example.